# Jenkins 2.0 validate pull request message

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

We use Jenkins 2.0 with the new multibranch pipeline job. Each pull request generates a new job PR-{number}. We want to make some validations on the pull request messages.

Is there any way to get the **pull request message** inside the Pipeline script?

Thank you in advance for any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get the PR title with `env.CHANGE_TITLE`, but for the message body you'll have to do an API call to GitHub.